# Custom search crawlers for external sources

Tags: search

I am working on SharePoint 2013. I would like to add few search sources in my search page.

My sources are: Websites, Documents, Databases and APIs.

What is the best way for this task? BCS? If you can refer me to code examples it would be great.

Comment: Why would you want to use BCS?Are you connecting to any external system.Within SharePoint Search you can configure your result sources with query transforms to get the results

Comment: @rjv91 I need to crawl websites, get data from files and from other databases like sql and mongo. I dont want to use BSC i will be happy to know what is the most appropriate way to do this

Comment: Did you get solution to this problem??

Comment: @JohnZachariah not yet. The project had not started yet :)